# How exactly do you use Admin Themes?

Tags: templates, twitter-bootstrap, admin

I'm seeing all these really nice looking Twitter Bootstrap Admin templates, but I don't know exactly how I would implement them.  Are they for like WordPress sites?  If they are, will they work?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use them in any CMS. You get a similar folder structure to anything normal i.e. the img, css, js folders. For each page you create you just need to remember to include the required files i.e. the bootstrap stylesheet and JavaScript plugins

Here is a good referral:

https://wrapbootstrap.com/

Comment: have you actually used them? Bootstrap conflicts with wordpress out of the box. So unless the theme is built to overcome the conflicts it wont work.